Changing variables from one form in another form
Is there a way to change variables that are in Form1 from Form2?
I tried using method in Form1, and calling it from Form2.
Here is a method in Form1 to change variables that I wrote:
public void change(int newval)
{
    val = newval;
}

I tried calling it in Form2 by:
form1.change(newval)

where form1 would be passed in through a constructor:
Form1 form1;
public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    this.form1 = form1;
    InitializeComponent();
}

But I can't find a way to get Form1 as an object to pass it into the constructor.

How do you create Form2?

Is Form2 shown as Modal?

It gets very simple when you learn to use data bindings in this (and other) platforms. See Data binding overview (Windows Forms .NET) and its sibling Design great data sources with change notification (Windows Forms .NET) for starters

A simple way to make form1 accessible globally as Program.form1:
public static class Program
{
    public static Form1 form1;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        form1 = new Form1();
        Application.Run(form1);
    }
}

